# How can I add a specific object with javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexof, arrayobject

I have an array like that :

[image]

When I find 'finished', I split it and I want to display for each string having 'Getting', his links having 'HTTP_404'

My code is :

```
 var input = ['urlGettingF', '├─BROKEN─aquaHTTP_404', '├─BROKEN─url1HTTP_404', 'ok', 'urlok', 'Finished',
               'urlGettingF2', '├─BROKEN─url1HTTP_404', '├─BROKEN─url21HTTP_404', 'Finished',
               'urlGettingF3', 'url3ok', 'ok', 'Finished',
               'urlGettingF4', 'url4ok', 'ok', 'Finished'
              ];

  var inputDecouped = [];
  let Test=[];
  let start = '';
  let pageGetting='';
  let liens =[];
  let pages=[];
  let ok= false;
  let reference = {};
  let grouped = {};
  // Fonction pour la découpe du input en plusieurs tableaux selon Finished
  function ArrayToMultipleArrays(array) {
    let result = [[]];
    let index = 0;
    array.forEach((x, i) => {
      //console.log(index, i, x)
      // On va mettre les tableaus selon la valeur de x
      result[index].push(x);
      if ((i + 1) < array.length && x.includes('Finished')) {
        index++;
        result[index] = [];
      }
    });
    return result
  }
  
  inputDecouped = ArrayToMultipleArrays(input);
  for(let i=0; i<inputDecouped.length; i++){
    for(let k = 0 ; k< inputDecouped[i].length; k++ ){ 
      if(inputDecouped[i][k].indexOf('Getting') > -1 || inputDecouped[i][k].indexOf('HTTP_404') > -1 ){
       if(inputDecouped[i][k].indexOf('Getting') > -1 ){
         start = inputDecouped[i][k];
         pageGetting = start;
         ok= true
         //pages.push(({id:i, page: inputDecouped[i][k]}));
       }
      else if(inputDecouped[i][k].indexOf('HTTP_404') > -1 ){
        if(ok === true){
          liens=[];
          ok = false;
        }
        liens.push(inputDecouped[i][k]);
       }
      } 
   } 
  
       Test.push(({page:pageGetting, lien: liens}));
  
   
  }
  
  console.log(Test);
```

when I run it, I get :

[image]

But, I want the result will be :

```
[[object Object] {
  lien: ["├─BROKEN─aquaHTTP_404", "├─BROKEN─url1HTTP_404"],
  page: "urlGettingF"
}, [object Object] {
  lien: ["├─BROKEN─url1HTTP_404", "├─BROKEN─url21HTTP_404"],
  page: "urlGettingF2"
}]
```

My jsbin is : https://jsbin.com/loqagekiji/edit?js,console

How can I fix it ?

Comment: You might consider using class declarations. I've had some positive results when looping through small amounts of data and populating various arrays. You might also reference regex matching if you have another project like this one.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your jsbin and got your desired results by replacing

```
Test.push(({page:pageGetting, lien: liens}));
```

with

```
if (!ok) {
  Test.push(({page:pageGetting, lien: liens}));
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it works for any case. If it doesn't, add the non-working case in a jsbin so we can see what can be done.

Answer (score 1):

This might help.

```js
var input = ['urlGettingF', '├─BROKEN─aquaHTTP_404', '├─BROKEN─url1HTTP_404', 'ok', 'urlok', 'Finished', 'urlGettingF2', '├─BROKEN─url1HTTP_404', '├─BROKEN─url21HTTP_404', 'Finished', 'urlGettingF3', 'url3ok', 'ok', 'Finished', 'urlGettingF4', 'url4ok', 'ok', 'Finished'];

let record = []
const result = input.reduce((p, c) => 
    (((/^Finished$/.test(c) && /HTTP_404/.test(record[1])) 
        ? ((p = [...p, { lien: [record[1], record[2]], page: record[0] }]), (record = []))
        : (record.push(c))), 
     p),[])
console.log(result)
```